# Laravel 5.1 redirect withErrors() empty in view

Tags: php, laravel, session

I had an issue with occasional TokenMismatchExceptions so I decided to to add

```
if($e instanceof TokenMismatchException)
{
    return \Redirect::to('auth/login')->withErrors(['Seems like you may have waited to long to use this application. Please refresh and try again.']);
}
```

to the app/Exceptions/Handler.php file in the `render` function.

I've try a number of different ways to redirect and the view never shows the errors. The view will show errors if I have incorrect login information though.

If I kill the script and dump the session I can see the errors but if I dump the session in the view the errors object is empty.

View

```
@if (isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0)
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <ul>
           @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
           @endforeach
       </ul>
   </div>
@endif
```

Route

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

/**
 * Need to be logged in to access all of these routes.
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return Redirect::to('/home');
    });
});
```

Laravel 5.1

Comment: change `{{ $error }}` to `{!! $error !!}`

Comment: I've dumped the variable in the view and it's empty

Comment: Is this in your view `var_dump($errors)`?

Comment: `var_dump(Session::all());` Edit - Not var_dump($errors) since that doesn't exist

Comment: Why not use session? `$request->session()->flash('error', message here);`

Comment: I didn't do that because the redirect has a function named withError and this was an error. I've tried using the `$request->session()->flash('error', message here);` and then `Redirect::back()` but `var_dump(Session::all());` is still empty

Comment: @Ethan22 have you found a solution?

Comment: @Haring10 no I was not able to. I just glanced over the code as it's been a while but it doesn't look like I made any changed for this. I believe, since I only have a few users, I left it up to them to clear their cookies if they run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return redirect('auth/login')->with('errors', ['Seems like you may have waited to long to use this application. Please refresh and try again.']);
```

And then in your view:

```
@if (session('errors'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach (session('errors') as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Nothing. `var_dump(Session:all())` still only shows the _token